# Can i compile Android studio project in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: android, eclipse, compilation, ide

I got an android studio project, and just for compile it takes 5-6minutes. I would like to know if I can compile It in Visual Studio Code or in Eclipse?

Comment: Can you give more information about your project setup, like Android Studio version, the code snippet in build.gradle file, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Android Studio Project in Eclipse or Visual Code but I'd strongly advise against it. Android Studio is the best ide for android projects. Massive android projects take few seconds to compile in android studio. If its taking 5-6 minutes then something is not configured properly.